# What is the best way to validate XML w.r.t XSD using Free XML Validator?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-validation

I need to validate XML against XSD and so what are free XML Validator available out there that could be useful for my task.

Thanks.

Comment: In code? What language? On the command line?

Comment: Writing your own XSD validator in C#/.NET is a matter of max. 25 lines of code :-)

Comment: In Java Programming Language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/) has Java, C++, and Perl versions.

The perl version contains a command line validator for convenience.

The Java version [API](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/api.html) includes classes and example code for [validation](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/api/javax/xml/validation/package-summary.html)

Example code:

```
// parse an XML document into a DOM tree
DocumentBuilderFactory parserFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
parserFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder parser = parserFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = parser.parse(new File("instance.xml"));

// create a SchemaFactory capable of understanding WXS schemas
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

// load a WXS schema, represented by a Schema instance
Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(new File("mySchema.xsd"));
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);

// create a Validator instance, which can be used to validate an instance document
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

// validate the DOM tree
try {
    validator.validate(new DOMSource(document));
} catch (SAXException e) {
    // instance document is invalid!
}
```